# Modificar la última parte de una cadena string en bucle

Tags: java, string

Necesito saber como modificar la última parte de una cadena string en bucle en java. Tengo la cadena 0001 y necesito que vaya creciendo en 0002,0003...

No tengo ningún tipo de idea de como hacer, ya que con la instrucción replace no sé sustituir en bucle.

Comment: Lenguaje de programación?

Comment: java, ya lo dijo mas arriba

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Mientras tanto, prueba a jugar con... `String s = ""; for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++) s = String.format("%04d", i);`

Answer (score 1):

Aca te hice un ejemlo en java con ciclo FOR

```
String var = "0000";

    for(int i=1;i<4;i++){
        System.out.println(var.substring(0,var.length()-1) + String.valueOf(i));
    }
```

Basicamente la funcion **substring()** en mi caso reemplaza el ultimo caracter de la cadena por uno nuevo, que al principio es un numero int, pero lo casteo a string.

Si lo ejecutas en MAIN, mostrara por consola:

```
0001
0002
0003
```

Comment: Buenas, con la instrucción que dio NaCl solucione el problema, muchas gracias!